# Moving to WIn 7 x64 generates bunch of compile errors in Designer!

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, x86-64

I support small local customers with VB2008 and MS Access applications (not VBA!).  When I had to replace my machine, the new one came with Win7 64bit.  Things failed immediately.  I figured out how to compile VB for x86; but when I did that, I got a bunch of compile errors from the designer code, not my own.  Typical of the errors is this one:
===Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' can be called with these arguments:
'Public Function Add(name As String) As System.Data.DataTable': Value of type 'Lozier01_PaintInventory.ds.InventoryDataTable' cannot be converted to 'String'
'Public Sub Add(table As System.Data.DataTable)': Value of type 'Lozier01_PaintInventory.ds.InventoryDataTable' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable'.
===This is really frustrating -- can anyone explain what's happening and how to fix/avoid/work-around it?
Many thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

1) You may have files in your project that are hard-referened to the system32 directory  (which is now your 64 bit system directory) when in-fact they are located in C:\windows\SysWOW64 (now your 32 bit directory).

2) Also you may have files that your code is expecting to be registered to the GAC, but are not there either.

I hope this helps you.